# wpf web browser cpu issue

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, cpu-usage

I have a problem with wpf web browser control. I am doing some HTML handling using jQuery. I am using browser.InvokeScript method for invocation of the script. The script is carried out OK, with no problems, but i have an issue with the control. It takes up 50% of CPU. CPU usage is constant, even if I am not doing anything on the control. I minimize it, but CPU usage is constantly at 50%. Without InvokeScript, it has no problems, CPU usage is at normal level.

It seems that InvokeScript creates a problem. I use it to hide certain div's in the HTML. I cannot see what the problem could be. Did anyone have a problem like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you analyzed this with the WPF Performance Suite? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx

If you do that, the performance suite will probably give you your answer.

Comment: Thank you, I found the issue using performance suite, had some problems with rendering